# Restore old input in laravel for multi input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an address book where a customer could have more than one address.

When the user is redirected back to the edit form after validation error, how do you restore the `old()` value?

I build my input like this:

```
@foreach ($addresses as $address)
    ...

    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="address_line1[{{ $address->id }}]" 
        value="{{ old('address_line1['. $address->id .']', $address->address_line1) }}" 
        class="span11" 
        placeholder="Address Line 1" />

    ...
@endforeach
```

This doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on `jedrzej`'s comment, I have managed to solve it like this:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="address_line1[{{ $address->id }}]" 
    value="{{ array_key_exists($address->id, old('address_line1', [])) ? old('address_line1')[$address->id] : $address->address_line1 }}" 
    class="span11" 
    placeholder="Nick Name" />
```

It's a bit long winded; but does the trick.